# identifying paid vs organic visitors from Google

Tags: php, analytics, refer

I am trying to create a mini analytics, and identifying where the visitors came from.

I am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to find out where each visitor came from, but I am struggling to find out if they came from **Google Adwords** or **Organic**.

Is there some trick to this? Is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` even the correct way to go about this?

Also if anyone knows how to do the same for **yahoo** and **bing**, then that sure would be handy too.

Comment: you will never know what any degree of accuracy ... adwords api - raw stats = organic.

Comment: Oh is that right? How come?

Comment: http is stateless by default

Comment: How can other 3rd party analytics work it out?

Comment: I think it may be possible to access the cookie google places on the visitor and view the referral information in there. Not sure how to though.

Comment: they would almost exclusively use HTTP_REFERER

Comment: so if a visitors comes from adwords or organic the HTTP_REFERER will still be https://www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it only with the HTTP's refereral, because the HTTPS protocol and Google deletes the URL parameters. Also, not so easy as you think, because there is a lot of variations to take in consideration (for example new.google.com, or Google.com)

Google Analytics mixes the referer pages and the UTM_parameters (Gclid is also included). I recomend you take a look of this document for more information
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en

But, I leave you a mini script that can help you, but it works only to detect the Google.

```
<?php
function detectCampaing()
{
   $ret = false;
   if(isset($_GET["gclid"])){ $ret = true;}
   if(isset($_GET["utm_source"])){ $ret = true;}
   if(isset($_GET["utm_medium"])){ $ret = true;}
   if(isset($_GET["utm_campaign"])){ $ret = true;}
    return $ret;
}


if(detectCampaing() == true ||strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], 'google') !== false){echo  "is campaign";}else{echo "is not a campaign";}
?>
```